# Commutativity between functors on sheaves of abelian groups

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, adjoint-functors, derived-functors

I am trying to understand certain properties of sheaf theory, but I'm having trouble finding the notions to answer my questions. I'd be really glad if someone could help me with the following. Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous map between topological space, and $\mathbb{C}$ be the constant sheaf.

---

Suppose that we are given a closed subset $i : A \hookrightarrow X$, such that $j : f(A) \hookrightarrow Y$ is closed as well. Do we have:

1. $j^* R^q f_* \mathbb{C} \simeq R^q f_{|A*} i^*  \mathbb{C}$,

where $R^qf_*$ is the higher direct image functor, and $f_{|A}$ is the restriction of $f$ to $A$.

Suppose moreover that we are given a sequence of closed subsets $i_l : A_l \hookrightarrow X$. Do we have:

2. $i^* \underset{l}{\oplus} i_{l*} \mathbb{C} \simeq \underset{l}{\oplus} i_{l|A_l \cap A*} \mathbb{C}.$

In other words, **does the restriction functor to a a closed subspace commute with higher direct images, an direct sums of extension functors from closed subspaces?**

---

Suppose now that all the previous subsets $i : A \hookrightarrow X$, $j : f(A) \hookrightarrow Y$,  $i_l : A_l \hookrightarrow X$ are open. I have seen somewhere that the right derived functor applied to $i_! i^*$ gives relative singular cohomology
$$R^q i_! i^* \mathcal{F} \simeq H^q(X, X \setminus A; \mathbb{C}).$$

3. Is there a reason why we use $i_!$ instead of $i_*$.

Do we have:

4. $j_! j^* R^q f_* \mathbb{C} \simeq R^q f_* i_! i^* \mathbb{C}$;
5. $i_! i^* \underset{l}{\oplus} i_{l*} \mathbb{C} \simeq \underset{l}{\oplus} i_{l| A_l \cap A !} i_{l|A_l \cap A}^* \mathbb{C}$.

In other words, **does the functor $i_! i^*$ commute with direct images, higher direct images, and direct sums of extension functors from closed subspaces?**

---

Let $\Gamma$ denote the global sections functor, and $\mathcal{F}_l$ be a sequence of sheaves of abelian groups. Do we have:

6. $R^q \Gamma (\underset{l}{\oplus} \mathcal{F}_l) \simeq \underset{l}{\oplus} R^q \Gamma (\mathcal{F}_l)$.

**In other words, does sheaf cohomology commute with direct sums?**

Comment: The question 6. is true, just take the direct sum of the injective resolutions of the $F_l$. I have no ideas for the other questions. Maybe there is something in Shapira and Kashiwara's book "Sheaves on manifolds" or "Sheaves in topology" by Dimca ?

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas. Could you expand your comment ? I'm not very familiar with injective resolutions.

Comment: So the definition of $R^q \Gamma F $ is as follows : let $I$ be an injective resolution of $F$. By definition this is an exact sequence $0 \to F \to I^0 \to I^1 \to \dots$ where the $I^k$ are injective sheaves. Then $R^q \Gamma F$ is the $q$-th cohomology group of the complex $\Gamma(I^0) \to \Gamma(I^1) \to \dots $. From this description 6. is clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nicolas. If I get what you're saying, the claim is that a natural injective resolution for the sum $\underset{l}{\oplus} F_l$ is given by the sum of the injective resolutions. Then, how do I see that the cohomology of this complex of sums is the sum of cohomology groups ?

Comment: Yes because a direct sum of injective objects is injective. Now the cohomology of a direct sum is the direct sum of the cohomology and you get the result.

Comment: And the fact that the cohomology of a direct sum is the direct sum of the cohomology, where does it come from ?

Comment: This is because kernel of a direct sum of morphisms is the direct sum of kernels, and same with image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help